# Navigate to AIR-swf inside AIR-container

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air

I have an AIR-container with html page as content:

```
<initialWindow>
    <content>index.html</content>
    ...
</initialWindow>
```

And I need to switch this html-page to air-swf file. I want to get result like:

```
<initialWindow>
    <content>index.swf</content>
    ...
</initialWindow>
```

When I try to change `document.location` then AIR internal webkit tries to display this swf and fails.
When I try `navigateToURL()` then default system browser tries to display this swf and fails too.

How could I switch to air-swf?
Thanks.